# Why Aren't the input commands working when another value is changing in the background in python

Tags: python, input, time

I want an input to register while the Mario.air value is counting down in the background. But input doesn't register for some reason. How do I make the input register? For example if you dive by type zz it registers the 1st time since the Mario.air value isn't counting down. But when it does start to count down The input suddenly stops registering.

```
import time
Start_2 = time.time()

class Mario:
  x_location = 0 
  y_location = 0
  z_location = 0 
  health = 3
  Water = False
  air = 63

class Water:
  x = 0
  y = -1
  z = 0
  bottom = -90
  top = 0 

start = input('say yes then press zz: ').lower() 
while start == 'yes':
  command = input('').lower()
  rules_2 = [Mario.x_location == Water.x,
  Mario.z_location == Water.z]
  if Mario.health == 0:
    print('Too bad')
    print('You died')
    print('Health: ', Mario.health)
    break
  if not Mario.Water:
    if all(rules_2):
      Mario.Water = True
      print('You are swimming')
  if command == 'zz' and not Mario.y_location == Water.bottom:
      Mario.y_location -= 5 
      print(Mario.x_location, Mario.y_location, Mario.z_location)
  if Mario.Water and Mario.y_location < -1:
   while Mario.air >= 0:
      Mario.air -= 1
      time.sleep(1)
      if Mario.air == 0:
        while Mario.air <= 0:
          Mario.health -= 1
          print('Health: ', Mario.health)
          time.sleep(3)
          if Mario.health == 0:
            print('You drowned')
            break
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I still allow the player to enter inputs when a time loop is still showing and running in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806724/how-do-i-still-allow-the-player-to-enter-inputs-when-a-time-loop-is-still-showin)

Comment: Not really since I want to figure out how to run a command in the background without it not registering the users' inputs.

Comment: It's fine though I'll just drop the concept